# No versions found with lein ancient

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

When running `lein ancient latest my.lib` I get the result `no versions found.`.  I have quite a few versions installed in my local m2 repo and they all work correctly with the project it's just that lein ancient can't seem to find them.  What possible reasons could there be for this, I can't find anything on the internet :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that lein-ancient relies on maven metadata such as https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/clojure/tools.logging/maven-metadata.xml to provide the versions, my repo just had static files in the correct structure :(